# Issues converting Pandas dataframe to a Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a bit of a confusing one:

I have the below script. I've converted a spark DF into a Pandas DF to carry out my functions.

I now have an output dataframe DF6, which is exactly what I needed.

I now need to write the data back to HDFS (Which Pandas is unable to do), so I need to convert the Pandas dataframe back to Spark and write it to the directory.

I've used the function below to do this, but unfortunately, it doesn't work

```
data_spark = spark_session.createDataFrame(df6)
data_spark.show()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keenek1/domainscript/another1.py", line 338, in <module>
    spark_df.show()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 350, in show
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o119.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 2080, .net, executor 81): org.apache.spark.SparkException:
Error from python worker:
  /usr/bin/python: No module named pyspark
```

Clearly there is a module called PySpark, because I get the correct output of df6 printed in the stdout. Which means, Spark has created a dataframe, converted it to Pandas & is just struggling with the last function.

Is there anything I can do about this?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import argparse, sys
from pyspark.sql import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
import glob
def create_session(appname):
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(appname)\
        .master('yarn')\
        .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://domain.net:9083")\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark_session
### START MAIN ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark_session = create_session('testing_files')
    #import file into dataframe
    start = time.time()
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #-----------------------------CALCUALTE DATES AND TIMES FOR QUERY----------------------------
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    dt_now = datetime.now()
    target_hour = int(dt_now.strftime('%s')) - 60*60*12
    today_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(target_hour).strftime('%Y%m%d')
    hour = datetime.fromtimestamp(target_hour).strftime('%H')
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #-----------------------------------CREATE DF FROM FILES ------------------------------------
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    schema = [\
        StructField('dmy',StringType(), True),\
        StructField('hh',StringType(), True),\
        very long list of fields....          
        ]
    final_structure = StructType(schema)

    df = spark_session.read\
        .option("header","false")\
        .option("delimiter", "\t")\
        .csv('hdfs://nameservice/data/data/dt=20181022/hour=11/*/*', final_structure)\
        .select('domain', 'optimisedsize')
    df2 = df.filter(df.domain != '----').groupby('domain').agg(sqlfunc.sum(df.optimisedsize).alias('sdsf'))
    df2.show()
    df3 = df2.toPandas()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-----------------------------DEFINE REQUIRED LOOKUP LISTS-----------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tld = ('co.uk', 'com', 'org', 'gov.uk', 'co', 'net', 'news', 'it', 'in' 'es', 'tw', 'pe', 'io', 'ca', 'cat', 'com.au',
  'com.ar', 'com.mt', 'com.co', 'ws', 'to', 'es', 'de', 'us', 'br', 'im', 'gr', 'cc', 'cn', 'org.uk', 'me', 'ovh', 'be',
  'tv', 'tech', '..', 'life', 'com.mx', 'pl', 'uk', 'ru', 'cz', 'st', 'info', 'mobi', 'today', 'eu', 'fi', 'jp', 'life',
  '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'earth', 'ninja', 'ie', 'im', 'ai', 'at', 'ch', 'ly', 'market', 'click',
  'fr', 'nl', 'se')
cdns = ('akamai', 'akamaized', 'maxcdn', 'cloudflare')
cleandomain = []

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-----------------------------SPLIT DOMAIN AT EVERY DOT--------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
index = df3.domain.str.split('.').tolist()
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------DEFINE FUNCTION FOR DOMAIN MANIPULATION-----------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def domfunction():
    #if it isn't a string, then print the value directly in the cleandomain list
    try:
        if str(x[-1]).isdigit():
            try:
                cleandomain.append(str(x[0])+'.'+str(x[1])+'.*.*')
            except IndexError:
                cleandomain.append(str(x)) 
        #if its in the CDN list, take a subdomain as well
        elif len(x) > 3 and str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip() in cdns:
            try:
                cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-1]))
            except IndexError:
                cleandomain.append(str(x))
        elif len(x) > 3 and str(x[len(x)-3]).rstrip() in cdns:
            try:
                cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-4])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
            except IndexError:
                cleandomain.append(str(x))
        #if its in the TLD list, do this
        elif len(x) > 2 and str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip()+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]).rstrip() in tld:
            try:
                cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
            except IndexError:
                cleandomain.append(str(x))
        elif len(x) > 2 and str(x[len(x)-1]) in tld:
            try:
                cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
            except IndexError:
                cleandomain.append(str(x))
        #if its not in the TLD list, do this
        else:
          cleandomain.append(str(x))
    except IndexError:
          cleandomain.append(str(x))
    except TypeError:
          cleandomain.append(str(x))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-------------LOOP OVER ITEMS WITHIN THE INDEX & CONCAT REQUIRED ELEMENTS--------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for x in index:
    domfunction()
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-------------------------------CONFIGURE OUTPUTS--------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#add the column to the dataframe

se = pd.Series(cleandomain)
df3['newdomain2'] = se.values
#select only the new domain column & usage & group by
df5 = df3.groupby(['newdomain2'],as_index = False)[['sdsf']].sum()
df6 = df5.sort_values(['sdsf'], ascending=["true"])
print(df6)
spark_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(df6)
spark_df.show()
spark_df.coalesce(100).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option('sep', '\t').mode('append').save('hdfs://nameservice/user/keenek1/domainlookup')
data_spark = spark_session.createDataFrame(df6)
data_spark.show()
print(df6)
end = time.time()
print("RunTime:")
print(end-start)
```

Comment: "Which means, Spark has created a dataframe, converted it to Pandas & is just struggling with the last function."... not quite. Spark operations are lazy in nature, which means data will not actually be loaded until it finds a command that will force evaluation .... these are operations such as show(), take(), collect(), and so on. So when you call show(), that is when it actually starts loading data and fails.

Comment: Its could quite ridiculous, but add at first line: import pyspark and told us about results.

Comment: Hi @coldspeed - I do get the results of df6 printed to stdout - so, the data has definitely been ingested by Spark & processed by Pandas by the time I get the error

Comment: adding import pyspark at the top also causes the same error @Paweł

Comment: Are you sure that your worker nodes have pyspark installed and are using the correct python version? Make sure your `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` variables are set correctly.

Comment: Hi Tim - yes, I am sure. The script fully runs, except the conversion statement, so I've already been calling the pyspark library, long before the error occurs. I'm not sure why that statement is causing issues